# Custom SSL Certificate Upload fails

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud

I own a custom domain. (i.e. domain.com) and have been routing the traffic to my Bluemix (Java Liberty) application just fine for the last year. (By adding the domain to the "Manage Domains" screen on the console.)

I've been trying to upload a SSL Certificate I purchased from Namecheap (RapidSSL) for this domain, to the console, but keep getting this error:

> [BXNUI0060E: A certificate for the 'domain.com' domain wasn't uploaded because a problem occurred contacting IBM DataPower Gateway.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NAEM.png)

I use the (.crt) certificate and (.pem) private key with password. I enter both those and the password in the appropriate fields and click 'Upload', but this appears after a minute. Also, I have tried with and without the intermediate (.crt) certificate, but still get the same error.

This error has been consistent for the last month. So I don't think its anything to do with my connection. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Just tried again today, AND IT WORKED. I did nothing different. So it must be a server/connection issue on Bluemix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible causes of this error would be a temporary service outage at Bluemix or a software mismatch due to a Bluemix service upgrade. You can check for outages and upgrade notices on the [Bluemix status page](https://status.eu-gb.bluemix.net). You can also find information about upgrades on the [IBM Bluemix blog](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/).

Comment: Yeah it worked about 2 weeks later. But Thanks for the tip!